# Word MailMerge partial range

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vsto, mailmerge

I have a VB.NET VSTO AddIn for Word.

In this project, I need to execute a MailMerge operation, but only for a partial range of the MergeSource.

In this example, let's assume the MergeSource contains 100 recipients.
I want to only include recipient 11-20.

Normally I do the following, but this includes ALL recipients.

```
Sub ExecuteMerge(ByRef Doc As Word.Document)
    Doc.MailMerge.Execute(False)
End Sub
```

What I would like to be able to do, is something like this:

```
Sub ExecuteMerge(ByRef Doc As Word.Document, Optional StartPos As Integer = 0, Optional EndPos As Integer = 0)
    If StartPos > 0 AndAlso StartPos <= Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount Then
        Doc.MailMerge.StartPosition = StartPos
    Else
        Doc.MailMerge.StartPosition = 1
    End If

    If EndPos > StartPos AndAlso EndPos <= Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount Then
        Doc.MailMerge.EndPosition = EndPos
    Else
        Doc.MailMerge.EndPosition = Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount
    End If
    Doc.MailMerge.Execute(False)
End Sub
```

Note: `.StartPosition` and `.EndPosition` is just pseudo-code, it doesn't exist as a property.

This is what I am looking for. How do I set the range of recipients to include in the merge?

Word must be able to do this, since when I perform MailMerge manually, I get this dialog:
[image: MailMerge dialog 11-20]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, you can set `.FirstRecord` and `.LastRecord` on the `DataSource`.

Like so:

```
Sub ExecuteWordMailMerge(ByRef Doc As Word.Document, Optional StartPos As Integer = 0, Optional EndPos As Integer = 0)
    If StartPos > 0 AndAlso StartPos <= Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount Then
        Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = StartPos
    Else
        Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = 1
    End If

    If EndPos > StartPos AndAlso EndPos <= Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount Then
        Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord = EndPos
    Else
        Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord = Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount
    End If
    Doc.MailMerge.Execute(False)
End Sub
```